# How to compare the same thing

Tags: comparative-constructions, comparative

[image]

I first wrote this and then realized I'm not comparing the same thing. "It" refers to "the amount of lamb consumed". That's to say, I'm comparing consumption with meats. What I should compare is consumption with consumption.

> **The amount of lamb consumed** also experienced a sharp decline. **It** went from the second highest of **the four meats** in 1979, at 150 grams, to the second lowest in 2004, at roughly 60 grams.

Does changing "of" to "among" fix the problem?

> The amount of lamb consumed also experienced a sharp decline. It went from the second highest **among** the four meats in 1979, at 150 grams, to the second lowest in 2004, at roughly 60 grams.

I also came up with this version. But I am worried "it" doesn't refer to "lamb" but refers to "the amount of lamb eaten" since "lamb" is buried in a prepositional phrase.

> The amount of lamb eaten also experienced a sharp decline. **It** went
> from the second most consumed meat in 1979, at 150 grams, to the
> second least consumed in 2004, at roughly 60 grams.

So I wonder if "this meat" would be better?

> The amount of lamb eaten also experienced a sharp decline. **This meat** went
> from the second most consumed in 1979, at 150 grams, to the
> second least consumed in 2004, at roughly 60 grams.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Could you explain why it's "from second place" instead of "from **the** second place"? I googled but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Nitpick Follows:  Your wording leads one to believe that there was a decline in lamb consumption between 1979 and 2004, during which time lamb went from the second most consumed to the second least.  Looking at your graph, however, this drop from second most consumed to second least consumed occurred between 1979 and 1980 (81?).  If you're tagging on extra years may as well make it run through 2022.

Comment: Be aware that fish is not regarded as meat.  Any statement assumes that you have already referred to the products being consumed.  You also have to say 150 grams per what. The clearest way of expressing this might be: **Sales of lamb also went into sharp decline, dropping from second place in 1979 at 150 grams (per....) to third in 2004 at 60 grams.**

Comment: @Learner110  It's idiomatic to say that someone/something came **in second/third/fourth place**, without the definite article. Equally **second/third/fourth place was occupied by....**. However, in another context, we might argue: **In the first place it's raining and in the second place I don't feel like going.** including the article.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. @RonaldSole, I have stated in the introductory paragraph that the graphs show the **weekly per-capita** consumption.  I still have to say "per person per week" whenever I include data?

Comment: That's a judgement. If you think that your statement is close enough to the opening sentence to make things clear, then no. If anybody needs to go back to the first sentence to see what you are referring to, then yes. Try reading it to a companion.

Comment: In a field of just four, I think it's really strange to speak of one "competitor" moving from the ***second highest*** position to the ***second lowest***. Sure - in this specific case the actual *numeric* drop in terms of the charted *amount* is quite pronounced. But in "league table" terms, the *position* of lamb consumption has slipped by just ***one place***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It" always refers to the thing previously mentioned. You are correct that the subject is "the amount of lamb", not lamb meat or its consumption in general. The amount of lamb consumed during that 25-year period is a fixed amount which cannot go up or down, so it would be wrong to say "it experienced a decline" if 'it' is fixed.

You should probably say:

> **Lamb consumption** experienced a sharp decline. It went from the second **most consumed** of the four meats in 1979, at 150 grams **per person per week**, to the second lowest in 2004, at roughly 60 grams.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That is to say, "lamb consumption" does not mean the same as "the amount of lamb consumed"? I thought they were the same.

Comment: @Learner110 No they are not the same in the way you use them. An "amount" is a collected total. When you say "the amount consumed in 25 years" you're referring to the summed amount in that entire period. That total amount cannot go up or down. What went down *during* that period is the amount *per week*, or the *rate of consumption*. You could express it different ways, my suggestion is only one way.